# Does Android developers need command line tools?

Tags: android, shell, command-line

I've been reading a book recently about professional development and how it is important to have a toolkit of command line tools which helps you a lot and saves you a lot of time, so it makes it worth your while to learn them. I am an android developer and I don't use the command line tools at all. All operations with VCS and everything else is provided by Android Studio.

So my question is: is there anyone working as a mobile developer who uses command line a lot and have a number of significant instruments which increase your performance? If so, please describe what you do. Links to other materials will be welcome too.

Comment: Using `adb`, `gradle`, etc. are fairly commonplace when working with CI servers.

Comment: This is all preference based ( and off topic for SO ). Android studio just puts a GUI around all the useful tools. When doing Android dev, I hardly touch the command line as the one click buttons do the same thing. On any other platform, I prefer the command line exclusively.

Comment: As @CommonsWare said, `adb` is very useful for CI tools, as it is for some other CLI tools such as `cordova`, `ionic` or `fastlane`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, using it for adb commands:

- adb connect (for wireless debugging)
- adb install (quick install of apk)
- adb pull (fast download of log files)
- adb uninstall (for uninstalling an apk fast).

Probably more, but I'm using these often. There are plugins that do these actions as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a solo shop or hobbyist there may not be much of a need for the command line. If you are working with others both locally and remote then you'll have to get into continuous integration builds and testing (Jenkins, et al.) and at that point having a good sense of the command line / scripting tools available will be necessary to figure out when those tools fail - different from your app not compiling.